# cannot access relationship after save in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Here's my code:

```
    if ($user->role == NULL){
        $user->setRole(Roles::Company);
        $user->save();//I can see that it works,the database is updated
        $user->fresh(['role']);
    }
    if ($user->role->id == Roles::Company)//error
        //do something
```

On the line with error I can see this:

> Trying to get property of non-object

I see that roles are null, but I don't know why and how to change this behavior. After refreshing page everything works just fine

Comment: could you provide the setRole() implementation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to get fresh user from `fresh` methodf like this:

```
$user = $user->fresh(['role']);
```

This method refresh a model and returns new instance (it isn't refreshed in the current instance).

Comment: It works! I was sure that if I use method and not a function, the object would apply it to itself. Thank you!